# Exclusion of my name as co author

Tags: publications

As part of my thesis, i gave archaeological bones for isotopic analysis. While in the first version the woman in charge of the analysis included my name in the article as co author, in the final version, which has already been published, the director of the excavation excluded my name and put his name instead of it. The journal in which it has been published  is very important for my curriculum. What can i do? Should I try to contact the journal having as a proof my thesis or ask the co aurhors why I have bern excluded and ask the journal for a correction? One year has already passed, but I decided to do what is right for me.

Comment: Is providing bones something that, by itself, would normally result in coauthorship in your field?

Comment: I have recorded all the bones, identifying them etc etc, i gave the sample choosing the right bones. I think i have the right to be referred as co author. What has the ditector did? At least they could include my name too, as the woman in charge of the analysis did at first. The director of the excavation who permitted me to study the bones has died and the new director has not very good relationship with me. I think what he did is immoral.

Comment: I havent just provided the bones..i did a thesis on them..

Comment: I also gave archaeological information..

Comment: Should a librarian be included as an author as they provided material that supports a thesis... If you did the analysis then I would say yes, for certain, you should be an author, but if not, then perhaps you should just expect an acknowledgement..

Comment: Yes, the identification of the specific bones was my personal work. I am not just a librarian, i am a zooarchaelogist. They used my identifications in the article!

Comment: And as a proof i have my on line thesis!

Comment: This issue should have been addressed a year ago during the publication process and, really, the authors should have been confirmed prior to the paper being submitted for publication.

Comment: But this was never happened. I m going to write to the journal. Isn t it my right? As a phd student i thought i hadn t the right.

Comment: The journal is very important, with high impact factor, i really need it for my curriculum ...when i asked one year ago what i can do a professor told me..oh..these things happen!

Comment: So i m asking, if i address my question to the journal, are they going to correct this? I have as a proof my phd on line. Its a cambridge university press publication.

Comment: How can someone defend his rights? Is there any legal department in these journals?

Comment: If they have a legal dept then it won't be there for you - they won't arbitrate a fight / disagreement between external parties (they may only rescind publication until the mess is cleared up...). You should consult your supervisor, Academic Dean, then perhaps go external to a lawyer if the outcome does not satisfy you. If you go to a lawyer just consider your future in the university...

Comment: This post and its answers may provide other points to consider : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/114170/72855

Comment: Did they cite your thesis?

Comment: In a suggestion for the rest of us, it might be useful later to offer to (and in fact to do) write a chapter of the paper. In this case, if you did not only provide the bone, but also wrote a section on where it originates from and what species it might be, you did not only contribute to the research that formed the paper, but also to the writing. I would say, this makes the main author more aware of your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know the specific situation of the paper or your thesis, but as a general rule, you should be an author if (i) you participated in the intellectual development of the research in question, and (ii) you participated in the work that needed to be done.

So, if the paper is about determining the isotopic structure and age analysis of a bone that you collected and for which you had previously done archaeological analyses (i.e., the paper and your study look at different things), then you probably do not deserve to be an author because you only provided a bone, but did not participate in the research *as reported on in the paper*.

On the other hand, if the paper does not only do some isotope analysis, but also describes the archaeological setting as an important part of the paper (i.e., your work; rather than just quote your previous work to provide a setting for the paper), then you *should* be an author on the paper.

In the end, we cannot tell you whether or not you should have been an author because we don't know what exactly the paper contains, and how that relates to your work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i think that my name should have been referred as a co author, because i gave archaeological information and i identified all the bones used for this analysis. All relevant papers refer as co authors the zooarchaeologists participating in the identifications done. In addition, what is the contribution of the director of the excavation? None!

Comment: The inclusion of the director is an entirely separate matter. Leave that for a separate question. But read again what I wrote above: Did you give archaeological information and identify bones *as part of this study*, or was the information you gave just included as background information with appropriate reference to your thesis? There is a comment under your question in which the analogy of a librarian is given: Did the librarian give you a book, or did they provide important intellectual contributions to the paper. You never seem to answer this question.

Comment: The problem is if i can do anything now. One of my supervisors was surprised by what these authors did, but she told me not to make things more complicated, even if i deserved to be referred...

Comment: Yes i identified bones used in this study. This was my job. They knew the different species because i told them  what they are.

Comment: And its very disappointing when you are young and older academics and researchers or professors and directors with hundrends of papers exclude you (when you are doing your first steps) to have one more paper alone...

Comment: I understand that you are disappointed and frustrated. But I can't help you with whether you are right or wrong because you never seem to answer my questions (or just don't understand them): I realize that they know what those bones are because you told them, but you have never explained what part in the study knowledge of the bones played.

Comment: The analogy with the librarian still holds: If you go to the library, ask for a book on X, and the librarian finds you a book on X, should the librarian be on the paper? The answer is no if X is a standard topic, say "medieval history at the time of Shakespeare". But the answer is yes if X is "a manuscript from medieval times that talks about the interaction of weather and water quality" -- finding such a manuscript is research itself.

Comment: Well, the fact that i did the identifications is something important, i havent just given the bones....i have understood what you have said..i recorded thousanfs of bones snd i daid using my knoeledge and studies what species tthey are...this is research...